# Android app that uses network for data retrieving/ data sending

Tags: android, networking

I am hoping in creating an app that works somewhat like the IKEA app where when the user select a category the app will (I assume) connect to a remote database and retrieve the relative information to display on the screen.

However, I am no programming expert in fact I am a newbie in android programming.  What kind of information should I be looking/studying before I start on this project?

Thanks in advance

Cheers~

HSL

Comment: You should read about how to request to server and get response in form of JSON/XML (JSON is easy to learn) and then parsing the response at clint side and read some info like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196234/simple-parse-json-from-url-on-android

Answer (score 0):

- You should first have some idea about networking with android. Android will not let you do networking in the main activity, therefore first check this out: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html
- Learn about activity,fragments and some xml for views in your app.
- Depending on the server side, you should design your connection to the server(web services,REST etc.) and data format(which form will you retrieve them, XMl,JSON...)

These are the first things come to my mind.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I will have a look at the info you provided.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need some web database web page and api to get data from it. Then you can get it with few different ways. In the links below are tutorials for XML and JSON examples:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qcotbMLjlA4&list=PLGLfVvz_LVvQUjiCc8lUT9aO0GsWA4uNe
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kt5wIEF7Lls&list=PLGLfVvz_LVvQUjiCc8lUT9aO0GsWA4uNe

Comment: Another tutorial for integrating web services: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTO5a1IeBl8

Comment: So basically if I have an app that needs "external" data, the best method would be linking it through a web database or web page?

Comment: Yes if you want to get data from "external" source you will need to get it from a server, web page,... You also have other options if you want to have that database on your device you can use a SQLite method. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUoGnvz_Yw4

Comment: Thank you so much, I will look into the info you provided