# Concatenating a string variable to a url properly

Tags: java, url

This is a follow up question of [Removing linebreak from php json output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053132/removing-linebreak-from-php-json-output).I couldn't find out what was making that problem but i somehow got rid of `value <br ...JSONException`.

**The Issue**

**when i use**

`String url = "http://192.168.32.1/Aafois/notice.php?isBatch=2010&section1='IT'";`

I get what i want i.e parsing the JSON to my android app.However when i use

```
String URL="http://192.168.32.1/Aafois/notice.php?isBatch="+isbatch+"&section1="+"'"+section1+"'";
```

I get `Value of java.lang.string can't be converted to JSONArray...JSONException`.So obviously there must be some problem there in this previous line.`isbatch` is an integer variable and `secton1` is a string variable which is `URL encoded to utf-8`.

**P.S**

I need `single quote` `'` before and after the variable `section1` as the url goes like 
`http://192.168.32.1/Aafois/notice.php?isBatch=2010&section1=`**'IT'**.

Comment: Can you print the resulting value of `URL` in the second case ?

Comment: Your simple question solved my problem.I checked those variables and they were returning null.Modified what needed.Worked as expected.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think of your variables is a `JSONArray`. To concatenate everything, it tries to turn your `String` into a `JSONArray`, which is not possible as your string is not JSON but part of a URL.

Comment: I checked those variables and they were returning null.Modified what needed.Worked as expected.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I checked for the variables `isBatch` and `section1`.They were returning null.Modified what was needed.Worked as expected.No more JSONException.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with this

```
    String batch= "C";
    String section = "2";
    String URL = "http://192.168.32.1/Aafois/notice.php?isBatch=";
    URL= URL.concat(batch+"& section ="+section);
```