# How to check if mysql is connected to android on eclipse

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch data from mysql database and populate it on a listview.

I am getting the ip address of my system like this

```
String link_url = "192.168.19.6";
```

Now in my wamp server I have a file called

```
/product_api/getDataProduct.php";
```

I now I want this file to called in eclipse I am doing this

```
link_url = Referensi.link+"/product_api/getDataProduct.php";
```

Please is this the right way of connecting android to mysql and how I do know if the file I am calling on eclipse is connected to mysql database.

this is the getDataOriduct.php file

```
<?php

include("koneksi.php");

$q = mysql_query('select * from produk');

    $v = '{"info" : [';
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($q))
    {
        $ob = array("<br>","<b>","</b>");
        if(strlen($v)<12)
        {
            $v .= '{"id_produk" : "'.$r['id_produk'].'", "nama_produk" : "'.$r['nama_produk'].'", "harga" : "'.$r['harga'].'", "deskripsi" : "'.$r['deskripsi'].'", "stok" : "'.$r['stok'].'", "gambar" : "'.str_replace($ob,"",$r['gambar']).'"}';
        }
        else
        {
            $v .= ',{"id_produk" : "'.$r['id_produk'].'", "nama_produk" : "'.$r['nama_produk'].'", "harga" : "'.$r['harga'].'", "deskripsi" : "'.$r['deskripsi'].'", "stok" : "'.$r['stok'].'", "gambar" : "'.str_replace($ob,"",$r['gambar']).'"}';
        }

    }
    $v .= ']}';
    echo $v;
?>
```

this is the included file

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db = mysql_select_db("android_tokobaju");
?>
```

this is where the error took place and this method is defined in oncreate method

```
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        String nlink_url = link_url +"/product_api/getDataProduct.php";
        JSONObject json = jParser.AmbilJson(nlink_url);
```

This is the stacktrace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ecommysql.yonandroid/com.ecommysql.yonandroid.PhotoProduk}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.
```

This is the AmbilJson function

```
public JSONObject AmbilJson(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        }
```

Please with the above is my database connected to mysql db. Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what is ur java code ?

Comment: How to check if my mysql is connected to android based on the above code

Comment: Which section of the java code do you want

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: If you downvote my question please be kind enough to point the issue to me clearly

Comment: Show this function `AmbilJson()` in `JSONParser` class

Comment: I have done that @AmanRawat

Comment: Add http in it like this `String link_url = "http://192.168.19.6";`  where you declare this variable `link_url`

Comment: Okay on doing that I get this error  
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Just change this `String link_url = "192.168.19.6";` to `String link_url = "http://192.168.19.6";`

Comment: I have done that and I am getting an error  
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111404/discussion-between-aman-rawat-and-jng).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in a very wrong direction my friend. There are lots of problem in the code which you shared. You have to know something before you start.

[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

After that
[JSON with PHP](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_php_example.htm)

After that your code will look like this

```
include("koneksi.php");

$q = mysql_query('select * from produk'); // change it too

    $v['info'] = [];


    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($q))
    {
        $ob = array("<br>","<b>","</b>");
        $temp['id_produk'] = $r['id_produk'];
        $temp['nama_produk'] = $r['nama_produk'];
        $temp['harga'] = $r['harga'];
        $temp['deskripsi'] = $r['deskripsi'];
        $temp['stok'] = $r['stok'];
        $temp['gambar'] = str_replace($ob,"",$r['gambar']);
        $v['info'][] = $temp;
    }

    echo json_encode($v);
?>
```

After that on android side you have to use

[Simple parse JSON from URL on Android and display in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196234/simple-parse-json-from-url-on-android-and-display-in-listview)

> You can't connect android to **MySql** directly you have to use any server
>   side language which will fetch data from the mysql and feed to the
>   android. In your case  **PHP** is server side scripting language which is
>   fetching data from mysql and returning JSON as a response. By **Android**
>   making an **HTTP** request to the server you can get that **JSON** from the
>   server and then inflate the list with that data.

Comment: I am having this error Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.

Comment: Provide the android code and stack trace in your question so we can better understand

Comment: Which part of the android code do you want

Comment: The one where the error took place

Answer (score -1):

you should add username , password ,hostname and database.
add that they try again.

```
<?php
$username = "your_name";
$password = "your_password";
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$dbase ="your_database";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password,$dbase) 
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";



//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, model,year FROM cars");

//fetch tha data from the database 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "ID:".$row{'id'}." Name:".$row{'model'}."Year: ". //display the results
   $row{'year'}."<br>";
}
//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Comment: So can I call it from eclipse this way link_url = Referensi.link+"/product_api/getDataProduct.php";

Comment: I am getting this error Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.

Comment: @Moudiz i think mysql_connect use 3 parameter in it mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) and it is also depricated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: Is that the cause of my error?