# I want to parse JSON Object from URL ( not using JSON Array)

Tags: java, android, json

I tried the code shown below, but data not showing.

This is the URL from where I'm fetching the JSON Object

> http://ibacor.com/api/cek-resi?pengirim=jne&resi=1892297430009

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // Creating service handler class instance
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(url);
        obj.getJSONObject("query").getString("pengirim");
        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + obj);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is the best example to download and parse JSON. check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196234/simple-parse-json-from-url-on-android-and-display-in-listview?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Log.d("Response: ", "> " + obj.getJSONObject("query").getString("pengirim"));  do this. I think your code is ok

Answer (score 2):

You're not assigning the value returned by `obj.getJSONObject("query").getString("pengirim");` to anything, and you're logging the `JSONObject` itself. Try something like this:

```
String pengirim = obj.getJSONObject("query").getString("pengirim");
Log.d("Response: ", "> " + pengirim);
```

Answer (score 0):

How can I set the String URL?
The URL I'm trying to set is below.

This is working.

```
String data="data copy paste from url";
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(data);
```

But this is not working. Need help on this.

```
String url="http://ibacor.com/api/cek-resi?pengirim=jne&resi=1892297430009";
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(url);
```