# How to get data from a url and set in to textview in android

Tags: android

I want to set this data into Textview from a Url in android.

[{"EmpName":"TARAQ  TTTT","empjoin_empno":"1017","empjoin_bldgrp":"","dept_ename":"INSPECTION \u0026 VIGILANCE DEPARTMENT","dsg_ename":"CHIEF MANAGER","Manager":""}]

Comment: whats is the problem ??

Comment: Your question is too broad, and has multiple problems that need solutions. That said you need to look into Retrofit/other networking lib for network communication.

Comment: Have you already retrieved data from the url in the android side? Please be more specific.

Comment: no i never retrieved data from the url in the android side . i have just a link that gives me this data and i want to show this data into my textview in android side

Answer (score 0):

You have to get data from URL. You can use Http client to retrieve data https://stackoverflow.com/a/13196453/5558150

or you can use retrofit and similar libraries.
http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: I dont know how to get data from http client or retrofit is there any full example

Comment: Already i shared you a like there. Try the first link you will get json string at onPostExecute method

Comment: what key should i pass on the state of the "name" you have passed in getString of example.

Comment: You can learn json parsing here:  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm